# Why my Apache Tomcat is not able to execute simple JSP select database program?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jsp, tomcat

Please help me i've been trying to execute this from past 2 days tried searching in all the search engines & followed all the mentioned steps from various websites none of them were able to solve the problem. Where am i going wrong?

Note: I'm not using any kind of IDE. I've used notepad to type this program. File is saved as "select.jsp" in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\MyJSPSamples". I've already entered two sample data in my table.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>SELECT Operation</title>
 </head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EXAMPLE"
 user="root"  password="123"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
 <th>Emp ID</th>
 <th>First Name</th>
 <th>Last Name</th>
 <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
 <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
 <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are my environment variables:

```
CLASSPATH:%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib\jsp-api.jar`<br><br>
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`<br><br>
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`;
```

Database i'm using is MySql.

Here is my screenshots link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QihmJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code above html tag:
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
Put this code into head area style tag:

```
   table{
   border:1 px solid #000;
   margin: 0 auto;
         }
```

Put this code into body area:
     <%
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EXAMPLE", "root", "123");

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultset = statement
            .executeQuery("select * from employees");
%>
```

Put this code into Body Area too:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>EMP ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>last name</th>
            <th>Age</th>

        </tr>
        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <tr>
            <td> <%= resultset.getString(1) %></td>
            <td> <%= resultset.getString(2) %></td>
            <td> <%= resultset.getString(3) %></td>
            <td> <%= resultset.getString(4) %></td>

        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

And Add mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar into lib, this example is working fine for me. if there is any more problem, just make a comment. Enjoy

Comment: Did everything as you said & also added the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib" still not working Tomcat returning the same error. :-(

Comment: Hi have you checked...... your database is running? Check you build path: make right JRE version: To do this, right click your project name and click and build path and then click libraries and make sure right JRE.  The example is working fine ffrom my Tomcat 7. If still not working , please just let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the help I got the result not in Tomcat but by using GlassFish server the one that is built in NetBeans IDE. Followed all the steps given in netbeans website & i'm happy with the result.